# How can I add the moderation tools to comments on my website?

Tags: facebook-social-plugins

I recently changed my comment box for a facebook social plugin comment on my website.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script><fb:comments href="xmg.co.cc" num_posts="5" width="287" colorscheme="dark"></fb:comments>
```

It works perfectly fine except I have had trouble adding the moderation tools. When I add the code with my fb username: connorc419 nothing changes. When I am signed in no setting options appear.

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="{ConnorC419}"/>
```

I would also like to instead change the username to my websites Facebook page xmgxgamers if anybody could help me in applying the moderation tools.

the final code i came up with is:

```
<head>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
    <fb:comments href="xmg.co.cc" num_posts="5" width="287" colorscheme="dark">
    </fb:comments>
    <meta property="fb:admins" content="{connorc419}"/>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add your User ID and not your username. Also, the brackets {} should be removed.